# How to install PIL on Spyder(Anaconda 3)?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

This is the problem when I go on to install using conda install PIL
It gives me this:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - pil -> python 2.6*
  - python 3.6*
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

PIL seems not maintained any more. Just install pillow:

```
conda install pillow
```

and use just as if you had PIL installed :

```
from PIL import Image
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a shot once I return home.

Answer (score 5):

I'm able to fix issue by installing pillow version 5,please try once.

```
conda install --channel conda-forge pillow=5
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
from pil import Image
```

instead of

```
from PIL import Image
```