# How did my anaconda change to use Python 2.7?

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed Anaconda for Python 3.7, and I created an environment `tf` to install lots of library, including iPython. After I logged into iPython terminal, I can see that it is using Python 3.6. I have been using environment for a while.

However, today after I use `conda install pil` to install a library, i can see that a lot of libraries are updated. After the installation, when I logged into iPython again, it shows that "Python 2.7.15" in the same environment `tf`.

How can I switch back to use Python 3 in the environment `tf`? I don't understand how this get changed. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is--- yes it's annoying--- that Anaconda is studious about managing dependencies for you. So if your version of pil doesn't work with Python3 Anaconda will put Python2 in your environment for you. A solution would probably be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46717354/how-to-install-pil-on-spyderanaconda-3#46717512).

In other words, you need pillow not pil

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda manages dependencies and the python environment for your libraries, this being said `Pil` is for Python2 and `Pillow` is for Python3 more about that [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/imaging/).


If you would like to you `Pil` in a Python3 environment l would advise setting up a virtual environment.
This [link](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/) might help. With setting up virtual environments with different Python versions.


Finally of your desire is upgrading your anaconda to a Python 3 version you can use the command.

 `conda install python==$pythonversion$` , here '$pythonversion$' is the python version you desire 3.6.5 or otherwise